# Integrate auriotouch in another app

Tags: iphone

excuse me to create again this question, but I have another problem. I'm trying to integrate the aurioTouch Apple sample in my app. I have put all the code that was in `aurioTouchAppDelegate` in my app delegate file. The code runs, but some methods, like methods in EAGView file doesn't run, I don't know whym they are not called. 
Some help or hints are welcome...

Answer (score 1):

Have you integrate all the setting from Project's Build Settings. Actually I had the same issue but then I compare all the settings from Build Settings and found that some of the Linker flags were creating the problem and then was able to solve the problem. So whenever you have such problems try to go to Project's Build setting and compare all the keys. Mostly the Linker flags creates the problem in such cases.... hope this help to others also...

**EDIT**

After referring to your project. Notice that you have overloaded the property **view** of ViewController with your custom View  EAGLView. You have not separated customView and ViewController's view.

Also, one major thing is you have to **Initialize** your EAGLView and add it to your ViewController's view. and rest of the things will go on in EAGLView.